# How to add SSL to subdomain that points to a different server?

Tags: ssl, subdomain, ssl-certificate

I've got a webserver that has a single domain SSL certificate: https://secure.example.com

I also have a couple of subdomains that point to *different* servers:

- http://www.example.com, which points to the main server.
- http://subdomain.example.com which points to a completely different server.

What is the best way to add SSL to the subdomain https://subdomain.example.com

Is it possible to configure something like this with a wildcard certificate? Or is it better to purchase another single-domain certificate and install it on the seperate server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get a wildcard cert but that is probably more expensive than you need and you'd need to copy your private key to each server -- which really is not recommended unless you are a crypto expert. You are better off simply purchasing two more certs for the two additional machines.

Comment: Single Greatest answer on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Wild card certificates only cover domains on the same server. I believe it's because the key used in the certificate is tied back to the server.

If you want to add a certificate for sites on other servers you will need specific certificates for those server/domain combinations.

Comment: Not really, Chris. If you have a wildcard cert you will need to copy the private key to every server you want to serve with that wildcard cert, but if you do that it will work fine.

Comment: fair'nuff :) I was answering based on my (albeit limited) experience installing certs into IIS.

Comment: Private can be copied only when you have unlimited server license feasibility with certificate.