# How to add SSL with subdomain on different server?

Tags: ssl, subdomain, wildcard, plesk

I have the same issue as this guy: [How to add SSL to subdomain that points to a different server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958650/how-to-add-ssl-to-subdomain-that-points-to-a-different-server)

However, I have no clue how to do this.
I have purchased a Wildcard SSL and set sub.mydomain.com to the IP of the other server using DNS records (A record).

Everything is installed correctly on the main server, however on the sub.mydomain.com the SSL doesn't work.

I'm using Plesk Panel on Ubuntu 14.04

Any idea how I can make it work on the other server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting ?

No matter the subdomain is created on which server if you have certificate and private key you can install ssl on the subdomain